# SOLR 4.3 Modification of schema.xml not considered by the server

Tags: solr, xsd, jetty, field

I have the following error: [doc=testIngestID411] unknown field 'dateImport'

At the beginning I did not have the field 'dateImport' in my solr schema. I decided to add it after launching solr a few times. 
1. I added this field to schema.xml:

```
<filed name="dateImport" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

after the other pre-existing fields.

1. I removed all my existing documents using :

   `<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>`
2. Stopped SOLR (using ctrl+c or by killing the jar process)
3. Restarted SOLR (using java -jar start.jar)

Then, when I try to insert a document with a filed named dateImport I got :

`"unknown field 'dateImport'"`

Extra information:

If I modify one field which existed before (i.e which was there the first time I launched this SOLR core) the modification is well considered. For instance, if I change one field that was not required for required=true (and restart solr). Then I cannot add a document without specifying this field.

Also I have noticed, using the web admin interface: 
On the left there is a tab call "Schema", this schema contains all modifications (like the field dateImport). Above this tab there is another tab named "Schema Browser". The field 'dateImport' DOES NOT appear here :( .

What can I do to get this new field working?? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<filed ...` to `<field ...`